# ServiceStack - extending AutoQuery Metadata with

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

Using the SwaggerFeature plugin in ServiceStack, I can annotate the properties of a DTO using the ApiMember attribute.

Example:

```
[Route("/swagger/{Name}", "POST"]
public class MyRequestDto
{
    [ApiMember(Name="Name", Description = "Name Description",
        ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to include these additional annotations for properties in the AutoQuery metadata service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema for AutoQuery Metadata doesn't allow for this metadata which would change the scope and purpose of the AutoQuery Metadata.

This information is also redundant as this metadata about Services is maintained in the `/types/metadata` route which returns the [MetadataTypes DTO](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/MetadataTypes.cs#L96).